# Automatically chmod a file when doing git add?

Tags: linux, windows, git, chmod

I have an ubuntu development system using git to manage files, but I like to do my editing in QTCreator on a different (windows) system, so I have a windows network drive mapped to the ubuntu server.

However, it seems that whenever I save a file, it adds the execute flag on windows. Sometimes it changes from 664 to 764, and sometimes I've seen it change to 777.

So I've been doing a chmod 644  before I do my git add, but it's rather a pain in the ass, and sometimes I forget.

Is there a good way to either prevent windows/QT from adding the +x, or just have "git add" automatically chmod 664 my .c and .h files before staging/committing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

A solution might be to set `core.fileMode` variable to `false` in your `~/.gitconfig`. This makes git ignore the executable bit.

If you are using a FAT filesystem, you might want to set `core.ignorecase` to `true` as well.

**Old answer**

Assuming you commit on the Linux box, you can use a hook, in this case `.git/hooks/pre-commit`:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -type f -not -perm 0644 -exec chmod 644 {} \+
find . -type d -not -perm 0755 -exec chmod 755 {} \+
git add .
```

This is somewhat crude in the sense that forces all files and directories to a certain permission. You might want to add `chmod` commands for specific files if they need to have other permissions between the `find` and `git add`. On the other hand it is short and simple.

A more complex solution might use `git diff --cached --name-only` to check which files are actually going to be committed and would fix only those. But this would be more complex and wouldn't fix random permission changes.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only)
chmod 644 $FILES
```

Comment: Hmm, very dangerous haha. Had to git reset, it modified and added a  whole bunch of other files ;) Is there any way to make it so that it only modifies the files which are already staged for commit?

Edit: Just saw the 2nd paragraph, yeah, that would be better. How would one go about that? I don't care about random permission changes except for the files that are being submitted

Comment: @Jordan: The second para should use `git diff`. See updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to have chmodded the files after the commit, or at least not add the files with the modified permissions to the staged files. I tried doing "git add $FILES" but it didn't seem to like that

Comment: @Jordan There might be a better way. See updated answer.

Comment: Aha! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to fix files in an existing repo, for example executable bit, try this:

```
git ls-files “*.sh” | xargs git update-index –add –chmod=+x
git ls-files “*.exe” | xargs git update-index –add –chmod=+x
```

git ls-files is faster than "find"